# Limit of integral of a sequence of functions (check)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Let $f_n:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $$f_n(x)=n\,x^n.$$

I want to compute

$$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int^{1}_{0}f_n(x)dx.$$

I have the following:

\begin{align}
lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int^{1}_{0}f_n(x)dx &= lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1 n\,x^n dx\\
&=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{n\,x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}\\
&=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{n}{n+1}\right]\\
&=1
\end{align}

I just want to confirm this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine, just minor edit to remove $x=1$ and $x=0$ after you substituted them.

\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{n\,x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[\frac{n}{n+1}\right]\\
&=1
\end{align}

Comment: Actually why can’t dominated convergence theorem be applied here?

Comment: if the computation is correct, it means $f_n$ can't be dominated. Especially due to value close to $1$.